# creating 2 photo slideshows on one page

Tags: html, css, slideshow

I am currently trying to put two photo slide shows with a lightbox backdrop on my main page. The first one works fine once clicked but the second one only shows the backdrop with no photos.The code is completely written in both html and css.

I feel part of the problem may have to do with the IDs beyond that I dont know.
If anyone knows whats wrong, I would greatly appreciate your input.

Code is as follows

HTML

```
        <div class="drawings flex column">
        <h3 class="roman">Drawings</h3>
        <ul class="flex between">
            <li class="flex a-center center">
                <a href="#img1">
                    <img src="./img/dead_space_lurker_main.jpg" class="thumbnail">
                </a>
            </li>
            <li class="flex a-center center">
                <a href="#img2">
                    <img src="./img/dead_space_slasher_main.jpg" class="thumbnail">
                </a>
            </li>
            <li class="flex a-center center">
                <a href="#img3">
                    <img src="./img/dead_space_infector_main.jpg" class="thumbnail">
                </a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div>
        <ul>
            <li>
                <a href="#_" class="lightbox fix none z4 grid10 h10" id="img1">
                    <ul class="slides flex rel">
                        <input type="radio" name="radio-btn" id="img-1" class="none" checked />
                        <li class="slide-container flex">
                            <div class="slide flex abs opc0">
                                <img class="grid10 h10" src="http://farm9.staticflickr.com/8072/8346734966_f9cd7d0941_z.jpg" />
                            </div>
                            <div class="nav">
                                <label for="img-6" class="prev abs none z5 h10 varela a-center opc0">&#x2039;</label>
                                <label for="img-2" class="next abs none z5 h10 varela a-center opc0">&#x203a;</label>
                            </div>
                        </li>
                        <input type="radio" name="radio-btn" id="img-2" class="none"/>
                        <li class="slide-container flex">
                            <div class="slide flex abs opc0">
                                <img class="grid10 h10" src="http://farm9.staticflickr.com/8504/8365873811_d32571df3d_z.jpg" />
                            </div>
                            <div class="nav">
                                <label for="img-1" class="prev abs none z5 h10 varela a-center opc0">&#x2039;</label>
                                <label for="img-3" class="next abs none z5 h10 varela a-center opc0">&#x203a;</label>
                            </div>
                        </li>
                        <input type="radio" name="radio-btn" id="img-3" class="none"/>
                        <li class="slide-container flex">
                            <div class="slide flex abs opc0">
                                <img class="grid10 h10" src="http://farm9.staticflickr.com/8068/8250438572_d1a5917072_z.jpg" />
                            </div>
                            <div class="nav">
                                <label for="img-2" class="prev abs none z5 h10 varela a-center opc0">&#x2039;</label>
                                <label for="img-4" class="next abs none z5 h10 varela a-center opc0">&#x203a;</label>
                            </div>
                        </li>
                        <input type="radio" name="radio-btn" id="img-4" class="none"/>
                        <li class="slide-container flex">
                            <div class="slide flex abs opc0">
                                <img class="grid10 h10" src="http://farm9.staticflickr.com/8061/8237246833_54d8fa37f0_z.jpg" />
                            </div>
                            <div class="nav">
                                <label for="img-3" class="prev abs none z5 h10 varela a-center opc0">&#x2039;</label>
                                <label for="img-5" class="next abs none z5 h10 varela a-center opc0">&#x203a;</label>
                            </div>
                        </li>
                        <input type="radio" name="radio-btn" id="img-5" class="none"/>
                        <li class="slide-container flex">
                            <div class="slide flex abs opc0">
                                <img class="grid10 h10" src="http://farm9.staticflickr.com/8055/8098750623_66292a35c0_z.jpg" />
                            </div>
                            <div class="nav">
                                <label for="img-4" class="prev abs none z5 h10 varela a-center opc0">&#x2039;</label>
                                <label for="img-6" class="next abs none z5 h10 varela a-center opc0">&#x203a;</label>
                            </div>
                        </li>
                        <input type="radio" name="radio-btn" id="img-6" class="none"/>
                        <li class="slide-container flex">
                            <div class="slide flex abs opc0">
                                <img class="grid10 h10" src="http://farm9.staticflickr.com/8195/8098750703_797e102da2_z.jpg" />
                            </div>
                            <div class="nav">
                                <label for="img-5" class="prev abs none z5 h10 varela a-center opc0">&#x2039;</label>
                                <label for="img-1" class="next abs none z5 h10 varela a-center opc0">&#x203a;</label>
                            </div>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-dots flex center abs grid10">
                            <label for="img-1" class="nav-dot flex rel" id="img-dot-1"></label>
                            <label for="img-2" class="nav-dot flex rel" id="img-dot-2"></label>
                            <label for="img-3" class="nav-dot flex rel" id="img-dot-3"></label>
                            <label for="img-4" class="nav-dot flex rel" id="img-dot-4"></label>
                            <label for="img-5" class="nav-dot flex rel" id="img-dot-5"></label>
                            <label for="img-6" class="nav-dot flex rel" id="img-dot-6"></label>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div>
        <ul>
            <li>
                <a href="#_" class="lightbox fix none z4 grid10 h10" id="img2">
                    <ul class="slides flex rel">
                        <input type="radio" name="radio-btn" id="img-7" class="none" checked />
                        <li class="slide-container flex">
                            <div class="slide flex abs opc0">
                                <img class="grid10 h10" src="http://farm9.staticflickr.com/8072/8346734966_f9cd7d0941_z.jpg" />
                            </div>
                            <div class="nav">
                                <label for="img-12" class="prev abs none z5 h10 varela a-center opc0">&#x2039;</label>
                                <label for="img-8" class="next abs none z5 h10 varela a-center opc0">&#x203a;</label>
                            </div>
                        </li>
                        <input type="radio" name="radio-btn" id="img-8" class="none"/>
                        <li class="slide-container flex">
                            <div class="slide flex abs opc0">
                                <img class="grid10 h10" src="http://farm9.staticflickr.com/8504/8365873811_d32571df3d_z.jpg" />
                            </div>
                            <div class="nav">
                                <label for="img-7" class="prev abs none z5 h10 varela a-center opc0">&#x2039;</label>
                                <label for="img-9" class="next abs none z5 h10 varela a-center opc0">&#x203a;</label>
                            </div>
                        </li>
                        <input type="radio" name="radio-btn" id="img-9" class="none"/>
                        <li class="slide-container flex">
                            <div class="slide flex abs opc0">
                                <img class="grid10 h10" src="http://farm9.staticflickr.com/8068/8250438572_d1a5917072_z.jpg" />
                            </div>
                            <div class="nav">
                                <label for="img-8" class="prev abs none z5 h10 varela a-center opc0">&#x2039;</label>
                                <label for="img-10" class="next abs none z5 h10 varela a-center opc0">&#x203a;</label>
                            </div>
                        </li>
                        <input type="radio" name="radio-btn" id="img-10" class="none"/>
                        <li class="slide-container flex">
                            <div class="slide flex abs opc0">
                                <img class="grid10 h10" src="http://farm9.staticflickr.com/8061/8237246833_54d8fa37f0_z.jpg" />
                            </div>
                            <div class="nav">
                                <label for="img-9" class="prev abs none z5 h10 varela a-center opc0">&#x2039;</label>
                                <label for="img-11" class="next abs none z5 h10 varela a-center opc0">&#x203a;</label>
                            </div>
                        </li>
                        <input type="radio" name="radio-btn" id="img-11" class="none"/>
                        <li class="slide-container flex">
                            <div class="slide flex abs opc0">
                                <img class="grid10 h10" src="http://farm9.staticflickr.com/8055/8098750623_66292a35c0_z.jpg" />
                            </div>
                            <div class="nav">
                                <label for="img-10" class="prev abs none z5 h10 varela a-center opc0">&#x2039;</label>
                                <label for="img-12" class="next abs none z5 h10 varela a-center opc0">&#x203a;</label>
                            </div>
                        </li>
                        <input type="radio" name="radio-btn" id="img-12" class="none"/>
                        <li class="slide-container flex">
                            <div class="slide flex abs opc0">
                                <img class="grid10 h10" src="http://farm9.staticflickr.com/8195/8098750703_797e102da2_z.jpg" />
                            </div>
                            <div class="nav">
                                <label for="img-11" class="prev abs none z5 h10 varela a-center opc0">&#x2039;</label>
                                <label for="img-7" class="next abs none z5 h10 varela a-center opc0">&#x203a;</label>
                            </div>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-dots flex center abs grid10">
                            <label for="img-7" class="nav-dot flex rel" id="img-dot-7"></label>
                            <label for="img-8" class="nav-dot flex rel" id="img-dot-8"></label>
                            <label for="img-9" class="nav-dot flex rel" id="img-dot-9"></label>
                            <label for="img-10" class="nav-dot flex rel" id="img-dot-10"></label>
                            <label for="img-11" class="nav-dot flex rel" id="img-dot-11"></label>
                            <label for="img-12" class="nav-dot flex rel" id="img-dot-12"></label>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </a>
            </li>
        </ul>
```

CSS

```
           .lightbox {
            @include positioning(0, 0, inherit, inherit);
            background: rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
        }

        .lightbox:target {
            outline: none;
            display: flex;
            flex-direction: column;
            justify-content: center;
        }

        .slides {
            @include gearCircle(900px, 700px, 0);
            padding: 0;
            margin: 0 auto;
        }

        .slide {
            @include gearCircle(900px, 700px, 0);
            top: 0;
            transform: scale(0);
            transition: all .7s ease-in-out;
        }

        .nav > label {
            width: 200px;
            transition: opacity .1s;
            color: $pureWhite;
            font-size: 156pt;
            line-height: 380px;
            background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, .3);
            text-shadow: 0px 0px 15px rgb(119, 119, 119);
        }

        .slide:hover + .nav label { 
            opacity: 0.5;
        }

        .nav label:hover { 
            opacity: 1;
        }

        .nav .next { 
            right: 0; 
        }

        input:checked + .slide-container  .slide {
            opacity: 1;
            transform: scale(1);
            transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
        }

        input:checked + .slide-container .nav label { 
            display: flex;
            flex-direction: column;
            justify-content: center;
        }

        .nav-dots {
            bottom: 9px;
            height: 11px;

            .nav-dot {
                @include gearCircle(11px, 11px, 100%);
                top: -5px;
                margin: 0 4px;
                background-color: rgba(119, 0, 20, 0.6);
            }
        }

        .nav-dots .nav-dot:hover {
            background-color: rgba(245, 0, 41, 0.8);
        }

        input#img-1:checked ~ .nav-dots label#img-dot-1,
        input#img-2:checked ~ .nav-dots label#img-dot-2,
        input#img-3:checked ~ .nav-dots label#img-dot-3,
        input#img-4:checked ~ .nav-dots label#img-dot-4,
        input#img-5:checked ~ .nav-dots label#img-dot-5,
        input#img-6:checked ~ .nav-dots label#img-dot-6 {
            background: $pureWhite;
        }

        input#img-7:checked ~ .nav-dots label#img-dot-7,
        input#img-8:checked ~ .nav-dots label#img-dot-8,
        input#img-9:checked ~ .nav-dots label#img-dot-9,
        input#img-10:checked ~ .nav-dots label#img-dot-10,
        input#img-11:checked ~ .nav-dots label#img-dot-11,
        input#img-12:checked ~ .nav-dots label#img-dot-12 {
            background: $pureWhite;
        }
```